# Driver update to ojdbc7.jar gives error for oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider

Tags: java, oracle12c

I have been using ojdbc14.jar earlier and now want to upgrade it to ojdbc7.jar for supporting oracle12c.

But while connecting server gives error for "oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider".

If I add oraclepki.jar to the classpath server starts up properly without any error.

I am trying to figure out what special got added in ojdbc7.jar that its asking me to add oraclepki.jar, As with ojdbc14.jar it never asked me to add oraclepki into my classpath.

Does anyone know what changes with ojdbc7 that's causing this error and what can be done to avoid adding oraclepki on classpath?

Comment: Is this a ClassNotFoundException exception ?

Comment: Thanks Clark, it just says errors: oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider, But I definately think its ClassNotFoundException as adding the Jar on classpath solves the problem.

Comment: Check that ojdbc14.jar is nowhere in the classpath

Comment: Already checked it, ojdbc14.jar is not present in classpath, Actually I tried deleting ojdbc14.jar from system itself.

Comment: There is some documentation on Oracle, you can add the `oraclepki.jar` or  `oraclepki103.jar` to the classpath; the jar is located in the `$ORACLE_HOME/jlib`

Comment: I am able to start my server by adding oraclepki.jar, but earlier in ojdbc14.jar it was not required. I am trying to understand the origin and nature of this conflict. Is Oracle 12c jdbc driver itself causing some changes that we have to add oraclepki on classpath.

Comment: This is in the documentation "ClassNotFoundException for this class oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider is thrown because this class is not present inside the custom driver module oracle which is configured for the datasource"

Comment: This seems to be related to the use of SSL and Oracle Wallet: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/clntsec.htm#JJDBC28328

Comment: Is Kenneth's comment really it?  This jar is needed just because they've modularised the JDBC driver now?
Does anyone have anything more reassuring as to why it's required?

Comment: As per my understanding earlier all the calls to OraclePKIProvider were using reflecion and hence we were able to find the class but with latest versions of driver the calls are direct and hence it throws such error.

Answer (score 3):

Check your classpath and make sure you remove the following: (if it exists)

`-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`

Comment: Worked for me, but I want to know what is the connection b/w usesplitverifier and that exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [issue](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2196488_1.html) recorded in the Oracle Support Database.  If you have Oracle Support, you can find out more there.  If not...

As Joseph Carroll states, removing the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` from your command line Java arguments might solve your problem.  The UseSplitVerifier argument basically tells Java to use an earlier, less stringent, byte code verifier (which was sometimes used to get older byte code instrumentation tools to work when upgrading from Java 6 to Java 7).  Unfortunately, it caused some problems when upgrading certain tools from Java 7 to Java 8.  Other things you might do include (per Oracle):

1. Upgrade to a java 7 compatible bytecode instrumentation tool.
2. Or, as
   a workaround, include oraclepki_121020.jar in the classpath. This is
   a valid workaround in case upgrading to a java 7 compatible bytecode
   instrumentation tool is not possible.

This [article](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/fabriziogiudici/2012/05/07/understanding-subtle-new-behaviours-jdk-7) talks about why `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` was added for using Java 7 with Oracle.  This [article](http://blog.takipi.com/oracles-latest-java-8-update-broke-your-tools-how-did-it-happen/) talks about using the `–noverify` flag with Java 8 instead of `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`.