# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider with sqlplus instantclient

Tags: linux, jar, classpath, java-7, instantclient

I am trying to upgrade CNM (comptel) application.While installing one .jar project (Please excuse I am not from java\linux camp) i got this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider with sqlplus instantclient in the installation logs.
Following is additional background:

1. I am using sqlplus instantclient with basic.OS is linux 64 bit Redhat 6.5
2. already installed java 7
3. created manually /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/**network/admin** folder. Created manually both tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files in it.Provided the user who is installing the application sufficient rights over these files.
4. sqlplus user/pwd@servicename; is working without any problem.
5. I have already gone through to the question and somehow found some clue for the problem:[Driver update to ojdbc7.jar gives error for oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318062/driver-update-to-ojdbc7-jar-gives-error-for-oracle-security-pki-oraclepkiprovide)
6. I could see that there are no jlib folder in my oracle_home and I have downloaded following files :osdt_core.jar,osdt_cert.jar and oraclepki.jar as suggested on one oracle standard documentation.
   I am planning to create and put these files in jlib folder but my concern is would that help or just like ankur singhal[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4914817/ankur-singhal) mentioned on above post,some classpath should also be set up.

I am using /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar oracle driver.

Paul